# I am attempting to arrange an unordered list vertically using HTML and CSS, instead of its current horizontal state

Tags: html, css

I have begun to create a webpage using HTML and CSS. Within this webpage's HTML code is a container (class="container").

Within this container is an unordered list (class="Header-List") which I would like to arrange horizontally. However, it is currently arranged vertically and I am struggling to change this

Any help would be much appreciated

Code is below;
Please see line 13 in HTML
Please see line 16 in CSS

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Landing Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="Header-Logo">Header Logo</div>
    <div>
    <ul class="Header-List">
      <li>Header Link One</li>
      <li>Header Link Two</li>   
      <li>Header Link Three</li>   
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: RGB(33, 41, 49);
  display: flex;
  height: 180px;
}
.Header-Logo {
  color: white;
  font: 16px sans serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 1;
}
.Header-List {
  color: white;
  font: 12px sans serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

I have attempted to use justify-content and align-items within the .Header-List in CSS, however this hasn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code to your css

```
.Header-List li{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `display: flex;` in your header to make it vertical

Add this:

```css
.Header-List li {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.Header-List li {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.